# Disable sitecore workflow command

Tags: workflow

For example I have three states A,B and C in a workflow.(Sitecore 8.0)

"A" have command "**Send Item**".
"B" have command "**Item Sent**". 
"C" is the     final State.

When I assign the workflow to an item and click on command "Send item", item moves to  state "B". "Item sent" command will be displayed for the user but I want to disable it for selection as I want to change state from "B" to "C" from Backend code based on reponse from external server. Is it possible ??

Thanks

Comment: Can't get you any exact details right now, but you should be able to do that with security..  you can find some blogs on that, e.g. http://blogs.perficient.com/digitaltransformation/2012/03/14/workflow-security-in-sitecore/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to see it as an admin, but hide from most authors, you can use Sitecore security on the command so that it is not visible to them. That way you can also have a back door for the system admin in case something fails in the code and you need to push it through.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide workflow commands using [Appearance Evaluator Type](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_development_team/posts/dynamic-workflow-command-appearance) field of the Workflow Command template. Just put the following value:

`Sitecore.Workflows.HiddenCommandStateEvaluator, Sitecore.Kernel`